# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Setting up authentication with reactjs, firebase (google auth), react-router and redux.

The problem is very simple but I can't find any resource online or answers to fix it.

Unable to read roperty of uid (user id with firebase) because it's telling me it's undefined? I've set this up that Private routes is a new component and it's been imported in my app router. I also plan to have a public routes as well.

Here is my code along with screenshots of error.

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = (props) => (
    <Route {...props} />
  );

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid <-error on this uid
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**AppRouter.js**

```
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'

<Route path="/" component={Login} exact={true}/>
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
<PrivateRoute path="/create" component={AddExp}/>
```

Screenshot of error when I'm logged out and try accessing `/create` private route

[image: Console errors: chrome]

*Updated to add redux store configure file*

```
import authenticationReducer from '../reducers/authentication'

export default () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            expenses: expensesReducer,
            authentication: authenticationReducer
        }),
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
    );
    return store;
};
```

**Auth reducer (just incase it's needed)**

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGIN':
        return {
            uid: action.uid
        };
        case 'LOGOUT':
        return {

        };
        default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Going to need to see how you are setting `auth` in your store

Comment: One moment sorry

Comment: Thank you this worked! I could not see this...

Comment: I thought it might be a problem with firebase uid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined` - means you are trying something like `variable.uid`  and `variable` is undefined.  Based on the line with the error, `state.auth` is undefined.

You should be able to look at your state there, either debug or just throw a `console.log` in your `mapStateToProps` to see what your state actually looks like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state:', state); // see what state is
  return {
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid <-error on this uid
  };
}
```

Looking at `combineReducers` is seems like you are putting the result of your `authenticationReducer` onto `state.authentication`, not `state.auth`...

```
combineReducers({
    expenses: expensesReducer,
    authentication: authenticationReducer
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `uid` on `state.authentication.uid` and trying to access it from `state.auth.uid`